# Golfed Inverse Ackermann Function

Tags: javascript, recursion, mathematics

The following was posted on [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125397/create-the-slowest-growing-function-you-can-in-under-100-bytes/125487#125487):

> Your job is to create the slowest growing function you can in no more than 100 bytes.

I did some Googling, and I was interested in the [Inverse Ackermann Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse):

$$
\alpha(m,n) = \min\{i \ge 1 : A(i, \lfloor \frac{m}{n} \rfloor \ge \log_2n\}
$$

Where \$A\$ is the Ackermann Function:

$$
A(m,n) =
\begin{cases}
n + 1, & \text{if} \space m = 0 \\
A(m - 1, 1) & \text{if} \space m > 0 \space \text{and} \space n = 0 \\
A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1)) & \text{if} \space m > 0 \space \text{and} \space n \gt 0
\end{cases}
$$

The Ackermann function itself is not too difficult to implement. Here is my implementation:

```js
A=(m,n)=>m?A(m-1,n?A(m,n-1):1):n+1
```

However, the mathematical stuff in the Inverse Ackermann stumped me. I came up with the following, also changing it from two variables to one:

```js
a=(m,n=m,i=1)=>{while(A(i,m/n|0)<=Math.log2(n))i++;return i}
```

However, that was yesterday. Today, I'm pretty sure I screwed some stuff up. `i` will always be one more than it should be, since the loop increments and then checks. So, the code should be this:

```js
a=(m,n=m,i=1)=>{while(A(i,m/n|0)<=Math.log2(n))i++;return i-1}
```

Now, of course this will StackOverflow very quickly. However, theoretically, it works.

Readable:

```js
function Ackermann(m, n) {
  return m ? Ackermann(m - 1, n ? Ackermann(m, n - 1) : 1) : n + 1;
}

function inverseAckermann(m) {
  var n = m;
  var i = 1;

  while (Ackermann(i, Math.floor(m / n)) <= Math.log2(n)) {
    i++;
  }

  return i - 1;
}
```

Any improvements to the implementation of the inverse Ackermann would be appreciated. I really wanted to use `Math.min` but I could not figure how to.

Note: I know this can be golfed more, and I know I can slow it down more. I'm more interested in my algorithm than scoring well in the challenge. Don't worry about keeping your suggestions/improvements golfed either :)

Comment: You are looking for improvements regarding the 'readable' code - such as better style, lower memory usage, better performance?

Comment: @le_m AFAIK the readable code and the golfed code do exactly the same thing, so you can approach either/both, but I assume you will want to mostly touch on the readable ungolfed code. I can remove the golfed code if it is irrelevant. Otherwise you are correct. I'm also interested in if I correctly translated the mathematical formula into code, or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: In the inverseAckermann function, if `n = m`, `m / n` always equals 1. I don't see anywhere where `n` is set.

Comment: @Artyer Yup, you are correct. I'm not sure I'm interpreting the math correctly - maybe I'm on the wrong stack. I'm really just trying to know how well I converted the formula from Wikipedia to a one-parameter formula.

Comment: @Artyer thinking on that: that might be intentional. If I'm interpreting it correctly, it's supposed to grow very slowly (it's the inverse of the Ackermann after all) so it's as if I'm just calling the Wikipedia formula with `1,1`, `2,2`, etc. Maybe not optimal, but it at least works. (Obviously it can just be replaced by `1` ATM)

Comment: Looks like you missed a closing parenthesis in the `while`-loop. I'm checking for other errors.

Comment: And I hope `i` is supposed to be an integer?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury thanks, I never ran the ungolfed version, only the golfed version. I'll fix that. `i` is preinitialized to `1` every time AFAIK (and I believe it is an integer)

Comment: My bad - `i` is constrained to be a non-negative integer as it is used as an input to the Ackermann function.

Comment: Review should likely be closed, as a lot of the content and comments afterwards seem to indicate that this code may or may not be a correct implementation and work as expected.

Comment: @MikeBrant you're probably right

Comment: Why don't you just un-golf the golfed version?

Comment: @SimonForsberg my real question was if my implementation was optimal or even correct, which is off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you're supposed to create the slowest-growing function possible, but that doesn't mean you necessarily need to make your function the slowest possible (LoL!).

As far as I can determine, your code for the Ackermann is mathematically correct - according to both Wikipedia and my (admittedly poor) sense of mathematical intuition.

#### `<BoringMaths>`

However, the inverse Ackermann as defined by Wikipedia is supposed to be a two-parameter function, and as such you cannot imitate it using a one-parameter function.

Also, you want a `do-while` loop here, so that the loop runs at least once even if the constraining condition is false at the start, as well be for my suggestion below. I don't think the return should be `i - 1` instead of `i` either, as you can potentially return 0 if it remains as-is, which is not a legal value.

What you could try, as the ending paragraph of the relevant section of the Wikipedia article mentions, is setting the parameter `m` to a constant - not `n`, and especially not making \$n=m\$ - although that works too.

Here, I'd suggest choosing \$m=0\$. Such a choice helps with golf-ability - you can get rid of the division and the `Math.floor` in one fell swoop - \$\lfloor\frac{m}{n}\rfloor\$ is always \$0\$, regardless of \$n\$ (assuming that `NaN`, when converted to integral type, is `0`, as it is in Java). So the loop condition basically becomes \$Ack(i, 0) < log_2(n)\$. Note the less-than (\$\lt\$), not less-than-or-equal-to (\$\le\$): this is the proper negation of the condition greater-than-or-equal-to (\$\ge\$).

Mathematically, how about a constant function, which is in fact the slowest growing function as it doesn't grow at all? Why not just return a constant and be done with it?

I think the PPCG question's rules forbid submitting a constant function, so let's not dwell on that any more (but it does make for a cheap trick, doesn't it?)

#### `</BoringMaths>`

#### `<NonCritical>`

A few small improvements for your implementation in the readable version

1. Extract out `Math.log2(n)` into a variable.
2. I think ES6+ gets you `let` and `const` - use them instead of `var`. As far as I remember, the former gets you proper scoping and the latter allows you to declare a named constant. I think my point (1) should have a `const` declaration.

#### Type Coercion is not readable!

Don't use implicit Boolean coercion of numbers in code which you claim to be "readable" - it isn't. Use proper comparisons in readable code, and leave the cool weak-typing hackery for the golfed version. How much does writing out the actual condition improve the readability of the code?

Everything else seems to be fine - naming, indentation, and all.

### `</NonCritical>`

### Suggested Code:

```
function Ackermann(m, n) {
  if (m < 0 || n < 0) {
     throw new TypeError("Arguments to Ackermann must be non-negative");
  }
  if (m == 0) {
     return n + 1;
  }
  else if (n == 0) {
     return Ackermann(m - 1, 1);
  } else {
     return Ackermann(m - 1, Ackermann(m, n - 1));
  }
}

function inverseAckermann(n) {
  const log2_n = Math.log2(n);
  let i = 0;
  // Taking `m` to be the constant 0 in the definition of the inverse Ackermann function
  do {
      ++i; // Pre-increment implies less side-effects
  } while (Ackermann(i, 0) < log2_n); 

  return i;
}
```